Why my Custom Context Menu Position Not Relative to my table
I have a problem with the context menu. When I click on any place on the page, the location of the context menu is correct, while when I click on any cell in the table, the context menu is far from the place I clicked. Click on it inside the crescent of the table.


$(document).ready(function() {

  const contextMenu = $(".wrapper_contextMenu");

  $(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let x = e.offsetX,
      y = e.offsetY,
      winWidth = window.innerWidth,
      winHeight = window.innerHeight,
      cmWidth = contextMenu.width(),
      cmHeight = contextMenu.height();



    x = x > winWidth - cmWidth ? winWidth - cmWidth - 5 : x;
    y = y > winHeight - cmHeight ? winHeight - cmHeight - 5 : y;

    contextMenu.css({
      left: `${x}px`,
      top: `${y}px`,
      visibility: "visible"
    });
  });

  $(document).on("click", function() {
    contextMenu.css("visibility", "hidden");
  });

  $("#data-table").on("click", function(e) {
    if (!e.ctrlKey && $(e.target).prop("tagName") !== "TD") {
      const selectedRows = $("#data-table .selected");
      selectedRows.removeClass("selected");
    }
  });

  $("#data-table").on("click", "td", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      const tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
      tr.addClass("selected");
      console.log(tr);
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!e.ctrlKey && $(e.target).prop("tagName") !== "TD") {
      const selectedRows = $("#data-table .selected");
      selectedRows.removeClass("selected");
    }
  });
});
/* Import Google Font - Poppins */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #8B55E9 0%, #5D6BE6 100%)
}

.selected {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.wrapper_contextMenu {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper_contextMenu .menu {
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

.content_context .item {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

.content_context .item:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.content_context .item span {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content_context .setting {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.content_context .share {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.share .share-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  right: -200px;
  top: -35px;
  padding: 13px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.share:hover .share-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="data-table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th data-column="ALARM_DESC" data-order="asc">
        ALARM_DESC
        <div class="resize-handle"></div>
      </th>
      <th data-column="ALARM_NAME" data-order="asc">
        ALARM_NAME
        <div class="resize-handle"></div>
      </th>
      <th data-column="APPLICAITON" data-order="asc">
        APPLICAITON
        <div class="resize-handle"></div>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr class="high-priority" style="">
      <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
      <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w 235421235334</td>
      <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="high-priority" style="">
      <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
      <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w sdfdsf</td>
      <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="high-priority" style="">
      <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
      <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w 235424</td>
      <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="high-priority" style="">
      <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
      <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w sdfdsf</td>
      <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="high-priority" style="">
      <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
      <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w 235424</td>
      <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <!-- <h3>dddffd</h3> -->
</table>

<div class="wrapper_contextMenu">
  <div class="content_context">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="item">
        <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
        <span>Preview</span>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
        <span>Preview</span>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
        <span>Preview</span>
      </li>
      <li class="item share">
        <div>
          <!-- <i class="uil uil-share"></i> -->
          <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
          <span>Share</span>
        </div>
        <!-- <i class="uil uil-angle-right"></i> -->
        <ul class="share-menu">
          <li class="item">
            <i class="uil uil-twitter-alt"></i>
            <span>Twitter</span>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <i class="uil uil-instagram"></i>
            <span>Instagram</span>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <i class="uil uil-dribbble"></i>
            <span>Dribble</span>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <i class="uil uil-telegram-alt"></i>
            <span>Telegram</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- </li> -->
        <li class="item">
          <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
          <span>Get Link</span>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
          <span>Rename</span>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
          <span>Delete</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="setting">
      <li class="item">
        <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
        <span>Settings</span>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I Tried To Edit this Code
const contextMenu = $(".wrapper_contextMenu");

$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let x = e.offsetX,
      y = e.offsetY,
      winWidth = window.innerWidth,
      winHeight = window.innerHeight,
      cmWidth = contextMenu.width(),
      cmHeight = contextMenu.height();
  


  x = x > winWidth - cmWidth ? winWidth - cmWidth - 5 : x;
  y = y > winHeight - cmHeight ? winHeight - cmHeight - 5 : y;

  contextMenu.css({
    left: `${x}px`,
    top: `${y}px`,
    visibility: "visible"
  });
});

but same reasult

Your snippet doesn't seem to demonstrate your problem. Please update it so it does. Don't post secondary code blocks. Just post your current or best attempt.

I created a CodePen for you with lots of comments. Something to note is, I switched it from jQuery to vanilla JavaScript. I'm sorry if that's inconvenient, but I know JavaScript and I don't know jQuery. Should be an easy switch if you require it to be in jQuery.
Anyway, here's the code below as well. The main issue you were running into has to do with the difference between offsetX/offsetY and clientX/clientY. In this case you'll want to use the client instead.
However, please look at the comments in my code to better understand other changes I made. Your current code has some important changes that need to be made so that it works reliably on all operating systems.


// I moved all elements to the top.
// This allows you to always know where to find your elements, in case something isn't working,
// and it helps readability when used later, like in the event listeners.
const contextMenu = document.querySelector(".wrapper_contextMenu"),
    dataTable = document.querySelector("#data-table");

// I moved your document click event and switch the closing of the context menu to a function.
// This makes the code more readable, and allows you to use this in other places easier.
function closeContextMenu() {
    contextMenu.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use clientX and clientY instead of offsetX and offsetY
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;

    // I changed the names of variables to be more clear.
    // This is best when other developers view the code.
    const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth,
        viewportHeight = window.innerHeight,
        contextMenuWidth = contextMenu.innerWidth,
        contextMenuHeight = contextMenu.innerHeight;

    // Rather than modifying values taken from the event directly,
    // I'm initializing the x and y values with the calculations.
    // This shouldn't make a difference if you prefer the other way
    const x =
        clientX > viewportWidth - contextMenuWidth
            ? viewportWidth - contextMenuWidth - 5
            : clientX;

    const y =
        clientY > viewportHeight - contextMenuHeight
            ? viewportHeight - contextMenuHeight - 5
            : clientY;

    contextMenu.style.left = `${x}px`;
    contextMenu.style.top = `${y}px`;
    contextMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
});

dataTable.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Destructuring from the event object makes it easier to use these variables later
    const { metaKey, target } = e;

    // Instead of using the ctrlKey, use metaKey.
    // This ensures the correct key is used (Control key on Windows and Command key on MacOS).
    if (!metaKey && target.tagName !== "TD") {
        const selectedRows = dataTable.querySelectorAll(".selected");

        selectedRows.forEach((row) => row.classList.remove("selected"));
    }

    // Combined dataTable click events into one to prevent confusion and errors.
    if (metaKey && target.tagName === "TD") {
        const tr = target.closest("tr");
        tr.classList.add("selected");
    }
});

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Same desctructuring note as above
    const { ctrlKey, metaKey, target } = e;

    // We need to check whether the control key is being pressed, because on MacOS it triggers the context menu.
    // Without this check it will trigger the contextmenu event and this click event at the same time,
    // causing the contextmenu to open and close immediately.
    if (!ctrlKey) closeContextMenu();

    // Same note about using metaKey instead of ctrlKey.
    if (!metaKey && target.tagName !== "TD") {
        const selectedRows = dataTable.querySelectorAll(".selected");

        selectedRows.forEach((row) => row.classList.remove("selected"));
    }
});
/* Import Google Font - Poppins */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #8b55e9 0%, #5d6be6 100%);
}

.selected {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.wrapper_contextMenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper_contextMenu .menu {
    padding: 10px 12px;
}

.content_context .item {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

.content_context .item:hover {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.content_context .item span {
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.content_context .setting {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.content_context .share {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.share .share-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    right: -200px;
    top: -35px;
    padding: 13px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.share:hover .share-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
<table id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr id="table-header">
            <th data-column="ALARM_DESC" data-order="asc">
                ALARM_DESC
                <div class="resize-handle"></div>
            </th>
            <th data-column="ALARM_NAME" data-order="asc">
                ALARM_NAME
                <div class="resize-handle"></div>
            </th>
            <th data-column="APPLICAITON" data-order="asc">
                APPLICAITON
                <div class="resize-handle"></div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr class="high-priority" style="">
            <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
            <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w 235421235334</td>
            <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="high-priority" style="">
            <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
            <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w sdfdsf</td>
            <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="high-priority" style="">
            <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
            <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w 235424</td>
            <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="high-priority" style="">
            <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
            <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w sdfdsf</td>
            <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="high-priority" style="">
            <td class="ALARM_DESC">sdklfsdlkfjdslk jsdlfk jlsfjsdlkfj</td>
            <td class="ALARM_NAME">utilization w 235424</td>
            <td class="APPLICAITON">SiteScope</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- <h3>dddffd</h3> -->
</table>

<div class="wrapper_contextMenu">
    <div class="content_context">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Preview</span>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Preview</span>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Preview</span>
            </li>
            <li class="item share">
                <div>
                    <!-- <i class="uil uil-share"></i> -->
                    <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                    <span>Share</span>
                </div>
                <!-- <i class="uil uil-angle-right"></i> -->
                <ul class="share-menu">
                    <li class="item">
                        <i class="uil uil-twitter-alt"></i>
                        <span>Twitter</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <i class="uil uil-instagram"></i>
                        <span>Instagram</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <i class="uil uil-dribbble"></i>
                        <span>Dribble</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <i class="uil uil-telegram-alt"></i>
                        <span>Telegram</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- </li> -->
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Get Link</span>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Rename</span>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Delete</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="setting">
            <li class="item">
                <img src="cursor (1).png" style="height: 30px;" alt="">
                <span>Settings</span>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



I hope this helps.
